# can't understand why I'm running multiple Windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I create a function where I perform actions with the grid of class Tk(). But when I run I have opened 2 or more Windows...

```py
def gridOverriding(master):
    """
    Метод организовывает сетку в соответствии с дизайном приложения.
    """
    if type(master) is type(Tk()):
        master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Ошибка типов', 'Не верный элемент [1]!')
```

```cs
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Tk()
    app.title('Курсовая работа')
    app.geometry('800x600')
    gridOverriding(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is your if statement in a function? where is __name__ being defined?

Comment: `if type(master) is type(Tk):`

Comment: There I do the checking on type =) There I do the checking on type and all =) do You think there is a mistake?

Comment: @tdammon No, that would not be in a function but instead just as shown and at the end of the code. `if __name__ == "__main__":` means to only run when the script is called directly (i.e. not to run what is in that block when you `import` the script). Hope that helps clear it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a window:

```
app = Tk()
```

... and this creates a window:

```
type(Tk())
```

Comment: OO! I saw..my inattention will destroy the world. Thank You= ) I deleted this block but still 2 Windows is called